# Flexible monitoring tool wanted

Tags: monitoring

I'm looking for a flexible monitoring tool, which should be able to:

1. Monitor public web endpoint and:

   - Validate REST API response body.
   - Validate response codes.
2. Monitor Azure resources: Cloud Services, Web Apps, SQL servers, VMs etc (Optional)
3. Support of custom monitoring scripts. For example, there is a PowerShell script which performs some checks and returns response if
   service healthy or not.
4. Provide availability/performance metrics based on monitoring statistics.
5. Raise alerts and send notifications

Tool should have a modern UI and support of multiple monitoring projects, each project should have own isolated settings.

Currently we are using MS application SCOM (System Center Operations Manager), but it's a very old tool and has a poor documentation and UI. But a very flexible and can monitor a lot of thing out of the box.

**Basically, is there something better and modern than SCOM?**

Comment: Software recommendations off topic here. Please ask at http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thanks, sorry for offtop

Comment: @StasKaratayev Look into CloudMonix @ http://cloudmonix.com - no other platform has better support for monitoring various Azure PAAS and IAAS services, it also has pretty cool automation capabilities - and it is pretty inexpensive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are using [HP-BSM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HP_Business_Service_Management), though expensive, it's very flexible and with many capabilities. It has every functionality that you wrote in your question.

Comment: As I said, SCOM also can do most of it, but it has no support, no good documentation, UI is 20+ years old. Is HP documented well? Does it have support?

Comment: Its very well documented and with great support. Highly recommended.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it out.